# Unexpected space between status bar and application ios 7 / 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I'm trying to use [onboarding](https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard) library start the app, I'm not using any navigation controller this is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_mobileOnboardVC = [[MobileOnboardViewController alloc]init];
_onboardVC =[_mobileOnboardVC loadOnboard];
_onboardVC.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.window.rootViewController = _onboardVC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And I'm getting this screen, can anyone point me out what's wrong with my code?  Thank you

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the structure of `_mobileOnboardVC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the background picture I'm using causing this problem. I'm using a big picture for the content image, the gap should be part of my background image. To solve this, I need use a small image like an icon as page content, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your code what you are using as a navigation system, but that appears to be a navigation bar on the screen and you can remove that by doing the following:

in your viewdidload of the view controller you are presenting, just type this:'

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:TRUE];
```

You should also put this in your viewWillAppear in the same viewcontroller so that when the page is loaded from a "back button" press, this bar is removed as well.

So, this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm not using any navigation controller here, I've edited the question

Comment: perfect, I have a hunch that this library is using a navigation system or is at least placing the bar there, one sec, I'm looking at this now

Comment: so, are the only two files you are using of the library the following: OnboardingViewController.h/m and OnboardingContentViewController.h/m from the look of it, this is all this library has for it's "source classes" is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I simply copy these two .m/.h files to my project

Comment: When I use their demo app, I don't have this gap, so I guess something wrong with my project settings

Comment: well, the demo can be used with or without a navigation controller, as is explained in the AppDelegate of their demo. also, their demo includes code that is commented out, which is fine, but the demo includes commented code that indicates that there is some sort of "completion handler" attached to th end of the onboarding process but there's no code for a completion handler when the rootViewController of the window is set.

Comment: This worries me since there's code in this library that hasn't be completed and even if it were complete, placing a completion handler on a navigation system, if done correctly, requires the jumping into Objective-C run time libraries. One more sec and I'll I have something for you, perhaps. But also, what other code is in your AppDelegate, is this all you do in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method?

Comment: also, "onboardVC" in your code, what's this value, i mean what kind of controller is this "onboardVC" and how are you declaring it?

Comment: my onboardVC is doing the same thing as their demo generateFirstDemoVC.

Comment: perfect, let me set up my own project, give me like five minutes, i'll see what it does for me

Comment: okay, just set up the project, as a single page application, gutted everything but what is necessary and I'm not having the same issue as you

Comment: Ill post my code, you can look at it and see if this is simpler to follow, I'm not using storyboards, this is all programmatic, If you are using storyboars, which I'm not sure if you are, then this will complicate it, but I"ll post anyway

Comment: It's the background picture I'm using causing this problem. I'm using a big picture for the content image, the gap should be part of my background image. To solve this, I need use a small image like an icon as page content, then it will work.

Comment: yessss, this could be part of it, in fact, here's the gist of my code, this is easier for you to see

Comment: other than this, there's nothign else in my single page app except for the source files. so it very well could be that image your are using. let me know if the image resizing doesn't work out

Comment: Thank you very much, it is the image size problem. But you inspired me a lot

Comment: no problem, I'm happy to help, helping like this forces me to learn more myself, good luck!